# Are requests for translators appropriate?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

See [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/821/looking-for-volunteer-german-translator-android-application). I would think this is *not* an appropriate question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, soliciting users in that manner is not appropriate. That sort of thing should be closed on sight **and** flagged for immediate deletion.

Answer (score 7):

No. I think such questions are not appropriate here.